# How to check if two char* file-paths are the same on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, filepath, case-insensitive

Since windows paths are case insensitive, is the case insensitive string comparison function `_stricmp` a reliable way to check if two paths are considered the same?

While this works for `[A-Za-z]`, will this work for other languages?
Or is a different method required for case insensitive path comparison?

Comment: I would assume it's the in the [Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-comparestringw).

Comment: Windows has shortcuts and implied drive letters, so different strings could still be the same file.

Comment: @stark while true - this is a separate issue issue. Two paths that are considered an exact match is distinct from two paths that happened to resolve to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

`tolower`/`toupper` are guaranteed to take the current locale in mind. So the portable way is to use either of those on the string first, then pass the result to `strcmp`.

As for how `strcmp` ranks locale-specific characters, it isn't well-defined, but if you are only using it to test for equality, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: From the docs it seems tolower/toupper don't handle unicode.

Comment: @ideasman42 `towlower`/`towupper` from wctype.h

Comment: That implies converting the `char *` to `wchat_t*` (fine, but it gets more involved).

Comment: @ideasman42 No, it implies that you should use the appropriate set of functions matching your encoding.

Comment: since there are multiple methods to perform this kind of operation - which function should be used to detect and convert the `char *`? which functions guarantee identical behavior to MS-Windows path handling?